Can I open Neotree in the current window instead of in a new one?
When I do a command like  :Neotree reveal it opens it in a new window on the left, when I want to it to show in the current window and hide the buffer that was there.

I got a response on Reddit with the answer. After loading Neotree, run this command on the focused window:
:Neotree current


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Looking at the documentation it is unclear it exist. I would use netrw for that (:Ex command)
If you want to stick with Neotree I would try:
Neoree reveal
wincmd r
wincmd p
q


Neoree reveal create the Neotree window
wincmd r switch the tree window and the old window content
wincmd p switch to the old window
qclose the old window


Im using Neotree because it can show me a persistent vertical list of all open buffers, including unnamed buffers.

I understand. Then indeed netrw is not a solution. Did you test the small script I have proposed?

Look at the answer I posted
